# react using non managed attributes with managed attributes

Tags: reactjs

Please refer my code below I wrote for just learning purpose :

```
import { useState } from "react";

function LoginForm() {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");


    let isInputTouched = false;

    const [isValidForm, setIsValidForm] = useState(false);

    function formSubmitHandler(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        isInputTouched = true;
        if (username.length < 10 || password.length < 10) {
            setIsValidForm(false);

            console.log((!isValidForm && isInputTouched));
            setUsername("");
            setPassword("");
            return;
        }
    }

    function usernameHandler(event) {
        const inputValue = event.target.value;
        setUsername(inputValue);
        isInputTouched = true;
    }
    function passwordHandler(event) {
        const inputValue = event.target.value;
        setPassword(inputValue);
        isInputTouched = true;
    }

    return (
        <div className="container w-50 border shadow p-5">
            <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                    <input onChange={usernameHandler} type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value={username} />
                    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input onChange={passwordHandler} type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" value={password} />
                </div>
                {(!isValidForm && isInputTouched) && < p className="text text-center text-danger">please enter valid email and password</p>}

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div >
    );
}

export default LoginForm;
```

My current understanding is that if any of the attributes managed by useState are updated, the jsx will be re evaluated. If that is the case, when I hit a submit button without entering any input jsx reevaluation should happen because I am calling setIsValidForm() in that. Now since I am updating isInputTouched manually (`isInputTouched = true;`) in the line before so this value should be considered anywhere its value is asked for but it wont trigger the reevaluation of jsx, but that should happen when I call `setIsValidForm(false);`. And post that my error warning should pop up : {(!isValidForm && isInputTouched) && < p className="text text-center text-danger">please enter valid email and password

}. But thats not hapenning.

Please help me understand where am I going wrong.

Comment: The most obvious solution is to do something like this: `const [isInputTouched, setIsInputTouched] = useState(false);`. However, if you want to try something different (you are learning after all), you could use `useRef()` and then set and access the value of `isInputTouched` via `isInputTouched.current`. E.g. `const isInputTouched = React.useRef(false);` and then `isInputTouched.current = true;`. That way it won't re-render every time you change that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Reason

This is happening because, the value of `isInputTouched` is not persisted across `rerenders`. Every time the component rerenders, the value of `isInputTouched` is reset to `false`.

---

##### Code

Here is an example to show, how the `isInputTouched` is erased on every rerender.

*Note: Check the Browser's console for clarity.*

Steps:

1. Click on `setRand` button then see console (no extra logs as no rerender, but you are expecting randVar change)
2. Click on `ToggleValid` button. There the value of `randVar` will be shown (in logs) before the state updation.
3. After the state updation, a new `table` will appear in `browser's logs` due to `rerender` on **state change**. You will notice that, `setRand` is reset to `false`.
   **Here is the gist**

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-bardeen-j6efc?file=/src/index.js

---

##### Solution

You can use `useState` for `isInputTouched` as well.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I missed to realise that re evaluation of jsx will also reset isInputTouched since its not managed by useState. Thanks You :)